# How can we maintain a healthy number of questions?

Tags: discussion

For quite a while we were getting a good number of new questions every day, but over the past week or so, the number of questions has fallen.

A good Stack Exchange site should reach a critical mass at which point people will naturally ask a certain number of questions. At present our membership is not high enough and we are not well-known enough to be people's first stop when considering where to ask a woodworking question.

In the meantime, how can we generate enough questions to maintain an active site and continue drawing more people in?

Comment: I would only note that a drop in activity at this stage is completely normal. You typically see an influx of traffic the early days due to increased anticipation and pent up demand, and then it falls off for a bit while the *organic* traffic starts to build up again as the site becomes more popular. This is a normal pattern of usage that happens on almost every site.

Comment: @RobertCartaino thanks for the info; it's nice to know this is common.

Comment: Personally, whenever I get a friend that asks me a question "in the real world," I point them to this site and answer it here.

Comment: @DanielB. so that's why we have to keep deleting all those off-topic questions that seem to be directed only to you... "Daniel, want to grab a bite to eat?" "Daniel, we're going to a movie this weekend. Want to join us?" "Daniel, why won't you get back to me?" "Daniel, this isn't really working out. Can you please start answering me in person instead of sending me here and then ignoring me?"

Comment: @rob yeah, sorry about that :p

Answer (score 6):

Here are some ways in which **you** can continue to contribute high-quality questions to the site:

1. When posting a question, consider whether it's possible to split that single question into multiple questions.
2. Go to any other woodworking sites you've participated on, and copy some of *your* past questions to this site.
3. Try to think of something you've done wrong in the past, and post a question about it.
4. Get out to your shop and build something. Every time you do something, ask yourself, "Why did I do it that way?" and consider whether that would make a good question.
5. Look at all the tools in your shop, and for each one ask yourself the following questions:

   1. What problems have I had with this tool?
   2. What do I know now that I wish I would have known before?
   3. Why did I buy this tool?
   4. Do I still use this tool? Why or why not?
   5. Am I using this tool in the most efficient way possible?
6. Consider tools that you *don't* own but have considered buying, and ask yourself the following questions:

   1. Why do I think I want that tool?
   2. Why haven't I bought that type of tool yet?
   3. What would I want to know before I would ever buy it?
7. Consider areas of woodworking that you do not currently practice, and assume for a moment that you want to add one or more of those to your repertoire. What questions do you have?
8. Watch popular woodworking youtube channels. Find something interesting they did to solve a problem and ask for solutions to that problem.
9. Organize community challenges; for example:

   - [Community Projects](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/49)
   - Topic challenges similar to those run by [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/12948)
10. Do research on common problems and pitfalls. [Google stuff](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=woodworking%20pitfalls&es_th=1)

    - This will either help come up with questions or
    - Be a good Q&A to debunk a myth if you know what you are reading is wrong

Note: This is a community wiki; please feel free to add your own ideas to the list above.