# Lets drum up some content! Who's up for community projects?

Tags: discussion

I have to tell you all:  I am in love with this site.  I love that there is a Stack Exchange site that covers a topic that I am passionate about.  So, I really want to help the site to succeed.

In discussion with some of the community team, it was mentioned that other sites help to get content by doing community projects/spotlights, like choosing a particular tag to focus on content for.

I know that on reddit's woodworking group, they do a new project every month.  I wonder if the community would be interested in doing something similar, with the idea being that executing the project might generate questions related to woodworking.

For example, if we were to focus on making a toy wagon for a child in our life, a reasonable question to ask might be something like this: [How does one make a perfect circle on a table saw?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/how-does-one-make-a-perfect-circle-on-a-table-saw)

I'm not sure what our groups tolerance is for sponsored projects or things like that, but it is an idea to maybe help create new helpful content for potential visitors.

Thoughts?

Comment: Movies.SE runs topic challenges to generate content; see http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1464/12948

Answer (score 4):

I love the idea.

In the beginning perhaps it would be a better idea to come up with simpler projects maybe that anyone could address. The really simple things like cutting boards, boxes, birdhouse / feeders. I don't see tool based focus being a good idea.

All of the above would help people learn about basic tools, joinery, finishing and the like.

**Constructive Criticism**

That being *I* don't see our tags making for a good focus. Looking at BowlTurners example the tools typically used for WorldBuilding are all in your mind. I'm not a member of WB but I like to read all the hot topics that show up. For many of them it is not that hard to drum up some basic ideas as many of them are rooted in your imagination.

Which makes using BowlTurners example tough since I don't own a [lathe](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lathe). I suppose I could theorize some things but I ultimately would have a hard time participating.

Comment: Ya, in the chat with Peter I pointed out how our tags would be hit and miss.  However, the basic idea is still there.

Comment: And we could possibly create a tag if needed for each project

Comment: That could easily work. It would be really neat to see different people work on the same project and when we come together see questions like "How did BowlTurner make that awesome part of his awesome thing"

Comment: The answer?  "Because he's bowlturner, of course!"

Comment: I just realized we were talking about two different types of group 'projects'.  At least Matt was talking about physically making things, and I was referring to 'focusing questions by highlighting a tag to ask about'

Comment: @bowlturner .... well crap thats what I though we were talking about... What I interpeted would still be a good idea. We could devote a chat room to it. Actually making things and showcaseing them

Comment: @Matt sorry, which?

Comment: @bowlturner You were right. I thought we were talking about making things

Comment: I think that could still be done, but I'm sure we would have a much smaller turnout than the other way.

Answer (score 3):

As I told Peter in chat, we do this in Worldbuilding and it really jumped the question/day count.

They have a meta question where tags are proposed for the bi-weekly challenge and everyone votes on the one they want next.  This in no way prevents other questions, but what it does do is give regular users an incentive to come up with questions about a specific topic, that they might not normally focus on.

If 'lathe' becomes a tag of the week/fortnight/month then people who might not use one might ask questions about them, how to use them etc. where they might not bother to otherwise.

Comment: How about a link so we can see what you do in Worldbuilding.

Comment: @ASTPace here's the main voting thread http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be

Answer (score 3):

Let's see how this goes.

### Community Project Wiki

**What is a community project?**

A community project is a task set in http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com to create some specific object out of mostly wood employing woodworking techniques.

The project is explained in full detail in the question that starts it. The general question of every community project is "How **did you** do/build/create/make.. this?". Notice that the question is not asking for thoughts on how this *could* be done. The only way to answer is to do as you're told and build the object.

**How can I find a community project?**

All of them have the tag `community-project`. Looking for questions with that tag will list all projects: https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-project

Additionally, users that start a community project should add it to this list:

- [Let's Build a Workbench!](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/community-project-lets-build-a-workbench)
- [Let's make a birdhouse!](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218/community-project-lets-make-a-birdhouse)

**How can I participate in a community project?**

Answer the question. In order to do that, you have to build the object (or whatever the project says). If you have questions on how to do things, ask them on the main site: http://woodworking.stackexchange.com. Asking questions is encouraged behaviour.

**What should I include in my answer?**

Well done! You finished the project.

Share your result in an answer to the question that started the project. The minimum content of your answer should be at least 1 picture to display your work. Feel free to explain your technique, findings and problems that you had throughout the project.

If you are sharing your project with the rest of the world, outside of woodworking.SE, please consider adding a link back to the original question.

**Is there a deadline for a project?**

No. A community project runs forever, to give new members the chance to participate. Users will vote their favourite answers up, but there can never be an accepted answer because of the way the question is asked.

**Can there be only one community project at a time?**

Absolutely not!  Please feel free to add community projects if you'd like to encourage your fellow woodworking.se members to try the project out for themselves.

Comment: Good explanation.  Sort of like taking a class online with optional project assignments.  No due dates.  I suppose the projects could range from no more than a suggestion (e.g. "Make child's wagon") to something with a complete set of shop drawings (e.g. "Make this jewelry box with dovetailed drawers.")  I'm actually getting a little hyped for this!  Do you have any projects up your sleeve?

Comment: I like the idea of the tag, but you mention [community-wiki] in the post but then link to [community-project] -- I prefer the community-project tag myself.

Comment: @Peter Grace I fixed that. Did you create the tag?

Comment: For the tag to be created and remain on the site, there needs to be at least one question associated with the tag.  So, we'll create it when someone suggests the first project :)

Comment: One thing too -- I think we should have many community projects, not just a single one, so if you have a project you think would be a fun skill-builder, why not post it in concert with the others?

Comment: @PeterGrace should every project link back to this FAQ? I cannot edit the link into your project questions. (I guess this is because you are a mod)

Comment: OK, I added paragraphs to both questions to link back to this faq.