# I think we should have a chatroom for showcasing our projects

Tags: discussion, chat, community-project

I have been thinking about this for a while but didn't want to have another chatroom that no one frequented which would then fizzle and die.

Now that [community-projects](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-projects) is starting to take off this idea might have a more permanent place. Our first [community project](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/lets-drum-up-some-content-whos-up-for-community-projects) was [Community Project: Lets build a workbench!](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/community-project-lets-build-a-workbench). Discussion was leaning towards keeping the answers lean to stimulate discussion and other questions. Trying to avoid a blog like posts about the entire process thereby keeping meta meta.

Do you think we should have a second chatroom that we would use for project pictures? So if anyone had worked on something and wanted to show it to the community they would have a place to showcase it. It would still exist to help stimulate other questions which would stay true to the concept of Community Projects?

We could call it:

- The ShowRoom
- Matt's Place
- The Art House
- Stuffatorium

I am not hot on any of those name just spit balling.

Comment: As I mentioned in chat, I think this is a great idea.

Comment: I like it.  I'd call it 'Swollen Thumbs"!

Comment: Assuming others are all on board with starting the chat room, we could start posting individual names as answers.

Comment: As best as I can tell 3 people are for this. You, bowlturner and me.

Comment: Personally, I feel like we should just keep all the chat to "The Workshop" so far.  If it gets too trafficked for site items, maybe then we talk about a separate chat room.  Chat rooms are pretty easy to start up.  It's harder to get people to go to a chat room if it doesn't have a lot of traffic.

Comment: @PeterGrace I was worried that having the one chat room would be saturated and good conversation could be dwarfed by pictures. But we can keep this on the back burner.

Comment: Matt, I agree with @PeterGrace. See my answer below http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/214/i-think-we-should-have-a-chatroom-for-showcasing-our-projects/217#217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe someday, but **now is not the time to split the *existing* chat room**.

If [community-projects](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-projects) is the hot new thing, you should leverage that popularity to bootstrap your *main* chat room. Bootstrapping ***one*** chat room is difficult enough, so I would not suggest splitting it into *two.*

I routinely see 3-15 hour gaps of inactivity in your main chat room, so you're not even close to achieving the [**network effects**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect) needed for it to be widely useful. When someone enters an empty chat room, they'll often just leave… usually forever.

I wouldn't split your existing chat room to make another. If you are anticipating overcrowding in your main chat room, that's a pretty high-quality problem. But I wouldn't create even *more* underutilized spaces to handle people who have not materialized yet. Leverage what you have now, or you may end up with no useful spaces at all. Good luck!

Comment: Fine by me. Back burner is fine. It's my first beta

Comment: Absolutely agree, from past experience moderating other discussion systems. Start it as a topic within the existing chat, and break it off when it is clear gnat it can be self-sustaining and is active enough that it's interfering with other activity. Splitting too soon is the surest way I know to kill a topic.

Comment: @keshlam Was not something I considered. Yeah the room is not busy now. Keep it all in one place until it becomes _too_ saturated.