# Answering Community Project Posts

Tags: discussion, community-project

If nothing else I am [proof](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1708/what-alternatives-are-there-for-pocket-screws) that doing to projects is insight for questions. Which was the goal in the first place.

I have just made a workbench from the: [Community Project: Lets build a workbench!](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/community-project-lets-build-a-workbench) and would like to make an answer.

Null covers this is a [wiki answer](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/203/128) from the original Meta question but that was not the focus.

Not a lot to draw upon yet since it Peter Grace has been the only one participating but do we need guidelines for answering those posts? Should we even answer at all? I think we should but I am trying to provide multiple view points.

Comment: I thought I had discussed this previously with @PeterGrace on meta, but I can't find right now so maybe it was in chat.

Comment: You did respond to his answer on the work bench question but it was comments.

Comment: Right; I did see my comment suggesting a list of tools, but I thought I had also suggested listing any questions that were spawned as a result of working on the project.

Comment: @rob maybe old age is getting to you :)

Comment: Actually you participated in the discussion too: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21393529#21393529

Comment: Do you feel better now :) You are not nuts. At least now you have it in a more formal setting. I don't even remember what I ate for lunch. You read most of the stuff I write you know i'm nuts

Comment: Yeah, now I know I'm not going crazy but I'm a little concerned for you! :D

Answer (score 1):

Since the point of these projects is partly to generate content for the main site, most of the techniques you learned should result in new questions or references to existing questions. I think it's also important to list the tools you used, in case someone wants to rise to the challenge and build the project using tools that nobody else has used yet--possibly spawning even more new questions.

It would be nice if we standardized on a concise format such as that shown below, keeping the prose to a minimum. I think only the tools used and the questions spawned or referenced should be required. If someone strays from the suggestions given in the question, it would be helpful to summarize those changes in a brief intro.

It isn't clear to me if the community projects are also intended to showcase people's work, but if so, it makes sense to encourage including other optional sections.

**Brief intro (optional)**

If you built the project but strayed from the suggested materials, tools, and techniques, this is the place to summarize what you did differently.

For example:

```
Instead of using pocket screws as suggested, I used hand-cut dovetails.
```

**Photo (optional)**

A photo of the finished project. In-progress photos are not necessary, as they will probably already be covered under the linked questions.

**Materials (optional)**

If you strayed from the suggested materials (or if there was no suggestion), you may include that here.

For example:

```
Quarter-sawn red cedar
```

**Tools used**

A list of the tools you used (or tried to use) in the process of building a project.

**Finish (optional)**

Brief of your finish, if any. For example, you may say that you painted it or that you applied 5 layers of wipe-on poly over stain. If you left the wood bare and don't plan to apply finish, you may simply say *none*.

**My new questions**

New questions you posted while working on this project, if any.

**Other helpful questions**

Other questions or answers which you would recommend reading when building this project. You should definitely include existing questions you personally referenced. You may also optionally include questions you think would be critical for a new woodworker who is building the project.

Comment: I wanted to add new question that I had made as a result..... Nice to see someone else thinks that as well. Thanks. Meta has been lonely lately so I was hoping to get people back.

Comment: It would make sense that actually making anything as a result of a project is optional. I for one only got my questions because I needed to actually to something to see the source of my questions.

Comment: @Matt I think if you don't actually build the project, you would just include that disclaimer in the intro and provide a list of questions you created as a result of thinking about the project. If you don't build the project, the "other helpful questions" section should also be optional.

Comment: Yes... that could work well. Helps keep the source of the question in one place as well to validate the Community Project.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I'd suggest just giving it a go, and ask for a response on what you write.  I'm sure you'll receive some opinions!  ;)