# Community Project: Let's make a birdhouse!

Tags: discussion, community-project

(This post is part of our community projects initiative to give users the opportunity to build something of value and in the process run into situations where they might have questions that our community could help answer!  Read more about the program [here](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/203/34).)

I've wanted to make a birdhouse for a while, so I figured I would suggest this as a potential community project!  There are many designs out on the internet, but I want to start simple.

This design is very simple and leaves some room for experimentation.  Have a look at the [US EPA's site](http://www.epa.gov/glnpo/greenacres/wildones/handbk/wo26bird.html) for this design.  If you find a better design out there and want to use that, share the plans (if they are freely available) along with your answer outlining the build!

[image: EPA birdhouse design from their website]

Comment: I'd rather build a bat house -- anything that eats skeeters is a friend of mine.